# Using an iframe in FireFox adds an extra <body> tag?

Tags: firefox, iframe

I have a webpage that uses an iframe to embed another one of our websites. However, FireFox is having issues rendering the contents of the iframe. When I inspected the raw html that was in the DOM, I noticed the following DOM structure inside the iframe:

```
#document
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body></body>
        <head> … </head>
        <body> … </body>
    </html>
```

Notice the body tag above the head tag - that's not in the source DOM! Removing it from within the developer tools fixes all of the rendering issues. For some reason, FireFox is adding a second body tag just before the head tag. Here is my puzzle:

1. The extra body is not in the source HTML being delivered
2. The extra tag only shows up in FireFox, Chrome and IE do not have it in there iframes
3. If I go straight to the url the iframe is loading in FireFox, the extra body tag is not there!
4. I have no addons - FireFox install is clean
5. I have the latest FireFox as of this post (v24.0)

Does anyone know what could be causing this? The site being embedded is really simple and does not have any javascript that could be adding this extra tag.

Comment: Try another browser. This sounds very strange.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: @Diodeus I agree that it is very strange. As mentioned above, IE (9 & 10) and Chrome do not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: I'm encountering this exact issue right now. Did you ever figure out a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes this to happen in some FF iframes and not others, but if you have access that allows you to change the code of the page that is loaded into the iframe, you could add this script that removes the first empty body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ffFixCount = 0,
    clearExtraBody = function(){
        var bodies = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
        if(bodies.length > 1){
            // assumes the empty, extra body tag you want to remove is the first one
            bodies[0].parentNode.removeChild(bodies[0]);
            window.clearInterval(ffBodyFixer);
        }else{
            ffFixCount++;
        }
        if(ffFixCount = 20){
            window.clearInterval(ffBodyFixer);
        }
    };

    //check for extra body tag will run every 100ms, 
    // 20 times, or, for 2 seconds (to give time for bug to happen)
    // or will stop if extra body tag is found
    var ffBodyFixer = window.setInterval(
        function(){     
           window.clearExtraBody();
        }, 100);
</script>
```